# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null while doing a random image election

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm new at javascript. I have this code, and I want to select a random image.

```js
const catbutton=document.getElementById('catbutton')
const cubebutton=document.getElementById('cubebutton')
const image=document.getElementById('image')
var arr= ["pr1.jpg", "pr2.jpg"]
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
alert(randomElement)
console.log(image.src=(randomElement));
```

```html
<img id=image src="" alt="">
```

Here is the image HTML part:

```
<img id=image src="" alt="">
```

Comment: So, you have all the js code inside `<script>` tag first in the page and then all the HTML markup? is that right?

Comment: @palaѕн I have the code in a .js file

Comment: Put quotes around image in HTML. `id="image"`

Comment: js file is added to the page before or after this `img` HTML tag?

Comment: Its working after the edit.

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky I didn't see I missed them! But still without working

Answer (score 0):

**Its working!!**

```js
const catbutton=document.getElementById('catbutton')
const cubebutton=document.getElementById('cubebutton')
const image=document.getElementById('image')
var arr= ["pr1.jpg", "pr2.jpg"]
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
image.src=(randomElement)
console.log(image.src);
```

```html
<img id=image src="" alt="">
```